# Dynamic root path route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, rack

How can I use dynamic root route if it depends on... weather, or current time, or whatever?

I thought about two ways: ApplicationController level and Rack redirect.

- With first solution I will check my dynamic state and redirect to particular page.
- Second solution is little more native as far as it uses routes level

For example

```
root :to => proc { |env| [ 302, {'Location'=> some_code }, [] ] }
```

But what I hope to see is how can I use simple lambda for route option like:

```
root :to => "mycontroller#myaction", :some_param => proc{ DateTime.now.hour }
```

It doesn't work but it shows my expectation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you'd need to initialize a parameter in the routing table when the same thing could be done in the controller:

```
params[:some_param] = DateTime.now.hour
```

You can also do the redirection inside the controller as required instead of leaning so heavily on the routing table using the `redirect_to` method.

Comment: Actually this is the way I am running now: redirecting in controller. But it changes a url in browser as well and it not looks like something native. I want just to tell Rails in routes: this routes is root at the evening and this one is for morning time :).

Comment: You could have a controller method that calls one of two different actions depending on the time of day. That would be a lot easier.

Comment: I also have a similar need. I understand it's almost a decade old question but still not well answered. The controller redirect makes it so the new route shows up on the browser which is not what we want. If you hit abc.com, depending on some conditions the root controller should redirect to some other controller actions but the URL shown should still be abc.com, and not abc.com/home or something else.

Comment: @AskarHussain There's limits on what sort of conditionals you can apply to routes. It's better to have one route with a smart controller rather than a smart route.

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone figured this out? Even though this question is a decade old now I still don't see a clean way of doing this in Rails. I have a route constraint for the root path. My need is once they get to that action then a few conditions would be checked and based on that the request should be ultimately processed by another controller action. I could do redirect_to but then the URL shown in the browser also changes, which is not what I want. If they are hitting abc.com they should still be kept at abc.com and not redirected to abc.com/home or something else. Anyone figured this out?

Comment: After a bit of trial and errors I'm leaning more towards tackling this with route constraints, and it may work, will report back if so.